# What is the relation called if ClassB::Method(); is in ClassA

Tags: php, oop

If I have the classes:

```
class ClassA
{
    private $data;

    public function GetData()
    {
        ClassB::ConvertData($this->data);
    }
}

class ClassB
{
    public static function ConvertData($data)
    {
        // Do something with data
        return $data;
    }
}
```

... then what is the relation between `ClassA` and `ClassB` called? The way I see it is not a composition, since `ClassA` has no object instance of `ClassB`, but still uses one of its methods. I'm leaning towards believing this is a dependency, but `ClassA` receives no instance of `ClassB` - neither through a constructor nor a method.

**Some additional, but related questions:**

1. Is there a difference if ClassB is abstract?
2. Is there a difference if there is no data passed/returned between those two classes?

Thanks for reading, I'd greatly appreciate your help. Just for some clarification, I attempted multiple searches for this, but I'm not sure on how I might search for this on the www.

Comment: There is no relation between them, so it does not have a dedicated name. PS: if a method is static - you must mark it with `static` keyword explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...**Call** is a [usage dependency](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html#usage) that specifies that the source operation invokes the target operation...
>
> Call is denoted with the standard stereotype `«call»` whose source is an operation and whose target is also an operation.
>
> This relationship may also be applied to the class containing an operation, with the meaning that there exists an operation in the class to which the dependency applies...
>
> Source: [uml-diagrams.org: Dependency in UML](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html)